# i need to have a listener for when input gets value in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input in my page and it get or set value from other function in js

now i want know any ways has when my input get or set value it run other

```
function and set other input value 
 here is my function set value to input1 
function showPoint(loc) {
    var docloc = myDiagram.transformDocToView(loc);
    var elt = document.getElementById("P18_LOC");
    elt.value = "view coordinates: " + docloc.x.toFixed(2) + " " + docloc.y.toFixed(2);
  }
```

now i need any event or listener when input get or set value run other function

i tired `onchange()` and `oninput()` and some more js event but i cant fix it

now : any way has to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When an element gets its value changed dynamically through code, user events like `change` and `input` don't fire off. What you need to do is manually call for those events to fire with the jQuery **[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** method.

```
function showPoint(loc) {
    var docloc = myDiagram.transformDocToView(loc);
    var elt = document.getElementById("P18_LOC");
    elt.value = "view coordinates: " + docloc.x.toFixed(2) + " " + docloc.y.toFixed(2);
    // Trigger the change event of the P18_LOC element
    $(elt).trigger("change");
}
```

Now, you can set up a `change` event handler for P18_LOC and it will fire whenever `showPoint()` is called.